# SharePoint FBA and windows authentication needs Trust Relationship between domains?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, trusted-domain

We have SharePoint configured on a domain, **Domain1** where FBA is implemented to get users authenticated from **Domain1**. Now we have another domain, **Domain2** which holds the other users that needs to get authenticated from same SharePoint using Windows Authentication. I have three questions,

1. Is this possible to authenticate users from a second domain using Windows Authentication?
2. Do both domains, Domain1 and Domain2 needs establish trust relationship with each other?
3. Do SharePoint needs to establish any kind of trust relationship with the second domain?

I would appreciate if a link to Microsoft's article or a implementation steps is provided for a concrete answer to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible to configure Active directory with multiple domains in SharePoint server. You can achieve this via adding building trust relationship between two domains. Please take a reference to this article: [How to Add Trust Domains in a SharePoint Farm](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-add-trust-domains-in-a-sharepoint-farm/)
2. Yes, you need to establish trust relationship between two domains.
3. No, trust relationship between two domains is enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot Allen for your thoughts. Can you please guide me if I have configured SharePoint on Domain1 and want to implement FBA for the same Domain1, and on the other hand I want to implement Windows Authentication for a Domain2 which do not have any trust relationship with Domain1 or SharePoint? Would this be achievable?